# Как доработать код для Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я нашёл код, благодаря которому, при добавлении любого товара в корзину из категории 277, автоматически добавляет товар с id 2316 в корзину.

Мне нужно доработать код так, чтобы категории проверялось две: 277 и 246. 
через запятую их перечислять нельзя. Может кто знает как это написать?

```
function aaptc_add_product_to_cart( $item_key, $product_id ) {
    $product_category_id    = 277; // категория к которой добавлять товар
    $product_cats_ids   = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    if ( ! is_admin() && in_array( $product_category_id, $product_cats_ids ) ) {
        $free_product_id = 2316;  // добавляемый товар
        $found      = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                    $found = true;

            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
        }        
    }    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'aaptc_add_product_to_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно применить минимум знаний PHP. Функция in_array() ищет значение в массиве. Соответственно если значение изменить на массив, то нужно пройтись по массиву и проверить каждое его значение на наличие в другом массиве.

В итоге нужно поменять $product_category_id вместо 277 на массив, например array(277,278). Далее убираем условие in_array($product_category_id, $product_cats_ids) и пишем более расширенную проверку:

```
$in_array = false;
foreach ( $product_category_id as $id ) {
    if ( in_array($id, $product_cats_ids) ) {
        $in_array = true;
    }
}
```

И уже после этого нужно дописать условие: $in_array == true. Финальный результат будет таким:

```
function aaptc_add_product_to_cart( $item_key, $product_id ) {
    $product_category_id = array(277,278); // категория к которой добавлять товар
    $product_cats_ids   = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

        $in_array = false;
        foreach ( $product_category_id as $id ) {
            if ( in_array($id, $product_cats_ids) ) {
                $in_array = true;
            }
        }

        if ( $in_array == true ) {
            $free_product_id = 2316;  // добавляемый товар
            $found      = false;
            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                        $found = true;

                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            }
        }
    }    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'aaptc_add_product_to_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: `$in_array == true` - так никто не пишет, только те, кто не понимает. что пишет. Это лишне.